# TYPO3 set session for fe_user and login

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18. I have problem with create session for user.

This code not working:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user_db);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $user_db;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'fe_typo_user', $user_db);
```

In front-end still looks like that user not logined. I sure, the problem is in session, because here

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user
```

I have user. Help me please anybody. Also I have cleared all caches anytime, and set normal in LocalConfiguration to loginSecurityLevel. Nothing work (

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the browser cookie by handy (if the the session is stored correctly in the fe_sessions table):

```
//  Reads session ID and create cookie
$session = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['ses_id'];
setcookie('fe_typo_user', $session, NULL, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to give TYPO3 a hint for login.
Edit page properties: in tab '**Behaviour**' set field '**Contains Plugin**' to  the value '**Website users**'.

Comment: Thank you! But I not sure that it is what I need. Because I need login user after his registration.